# How to use a custom function for a query

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have created the following function, and would like to query the names from my student table with an average grade point based on the scale used in Gradepoint. Any ideas? I have provided a select statement that joins my student,class, and grade table below.

```html
  DECLARE 

FUNCTION GradePoint(GRADE varchar2)
return number
is 
BEGIN
RETURN CASE grade
when 'A+' then 9
when 'A' then 8
when 'A-' then 7
when 'B+' then 6
when 'B' then 5
when 'B-' then 4
when 'C+' then 3
when 'C' then 2
when 'D'then 1
when 'F'then 0
else  -1
END;
END;


SELECT student.student_id, student.first_name, student.last_name, avg(gradepoint(class.grade))
FROM CLASS
JOIN STUDENT
  ON student.student_id = class.student_id
  JOIN course
  ON course.course_id = class.course_id
group by 1;
```

Comment: What's your oracle version? Is it 12 +?

Comment: my oracle version is 18

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @SayanMalakshinov indicates you can inline your function definition, this is great if you want function usable only within a single query - and there very many times when that is exactly is needed. But to be generally available you have to create is as a stored procedure (generic of procedure). In order for that you must first understand the block structure of PLSQL. PLSQL procedures have 2 main variants: Anonymous blocks and Named blocks. Both consistent of up to 3 sections: declaration, execution, and exception sections. For Anonymous blocks the declaration and exception sections are optional. The entire block in then terminated with an END statement.

```
    declare    -- Declaration section 
               -- contains local definitions
    begin      -- Execution section 
               -- contains the code
    exception  -- Exception Section 
      when ... -- contains code to handle specific exceptions 
      when ... -- that occur within the execution section   
    end;       -- Block terminates
```

Named blocks have the same structure except that the declaration section is also required, but instead of beginning with DECLARE it begins with either FUNCTION or PROCEDURE. Finally blocks maybe nested: a block is defined inside and another block. Anything defined in an outer block is available in the nested blocks. With some restrictions named blocks can nested (in the declaration section) in an anonymous block. And like any other definition within an anonymous block when the block terminates the definition of the named block goes out of scope.  

Now look at your code:

```
declare
function GradePoint(GRADE varchar2)
   ...
end; 
end;
```

The last is what you have: A named block, GradePoint, is nested in an anonymous block. For general availability replace DECLARE with the compiler directive CREATE. So:

```
create or replace 
function GradePoint(grade varchar2)
   ...
   select ...
        , case ...
          end; 
end GradePoint;
```

As far as your final query, I was confused what avg you wanted. Your description implied an overall grade point but your initial query implies grade point by student. Either way the window version of avg function gets the proper value. Try something like:

```
select distinct
       s.student_id
     , s.first_name
     , s.last_name
     , round(avg(GradePoint(cl.grade)) over (partition by s.student_id),2) gpa
     , round(avg(GradePoint(cl.grade)) over (),2)  overall_gpa
  from student s 
  join class   cl on cl.student_id = s.student_id
  join course  c  on c.course_id = cl.course_id 
 order by s.student_id;
```

**SIDE NOTE:** You should avoid CamelCase names. Internally Oracle converts these to upper case (all object types tables, columns, views, procedures, ,,, all named objects. Any reference it makes is with the upper cased value. So GradePoint will always appear as GRADEPOINT. In Oracle it is better to use Snake_Case convention. Yes it also will be upper cased but still easier to read. Meaning greater understanding and fewer errors, esp when items are closely named.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using oracle 18, you can define inline pl/sql functions in the query: https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/with-clause-enhancements-12cr1

```sql
WITH FUNCTION GradePoint(GRADE varchar2)
return number
is 
BEGIN
RETURN CASE grade
when 'A+' then 9
when 'A' then 8
when 'A-' then 7
when 'B+' then 6
when 'B' then 5
when 'B-' then 4
when 'C+' then 3
when 'C' then 2
when 'D'then 1
when 'F'then 0
else  -1
END;
END;
SELECT student.student_id, student.first_name, student.last_name, class.grade, GradePoint(class.grade) as gradepoint
FROM CLASS
JOIN STUDENT
  ON student.student_id = class.student_id
  JOIN course
  ON course.course_id = class.course_id
order by 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the Gradepoint function call with avg() and add group by student_id, first_name, last_name, grade.

Comment: Thats what I have been trying, but I cant get the syntax down

Comment: SELECT student.student_id, student.first_name, student.last_name, class.grade, AVG(GradePoint(class.grade) )as gradepoint
FROM CLASS
JOIN STUDENT
  ON student.student_id = class.student_id
  JOIN course
  ON course.course_id = class.course_id
group by 1;

Comment: I get a different error but I clearly dont know what im doing, I am going to keep reading up on pl/sql functions

Comment: group by doesn't work the same as order by.  you cannot reference the columns by number.

Comment: any way I do it I get the error:ORA-00904: "GRADEPOINT": invalid identifier

Answer (score 0):

did you mean

```
DECLARE 
FUNCTION GradePoint(GRADE varchar2)
return number
is 
BEGIN
RETURN CASE grade
when 'A+' then 9
when 'A' then 8
when 'A-' then 7
when 'B+' then 6
when 'B' then 5
when 'B-' then 4
when 'C+' then 3
when 'C' then 2
when 'D'then 1
when 'F'then 0
else  -1
END;
END;


SELECT student.student_id, student.first_name, student.last_name, class.grade,
(select avg(GradePoint) from CLASS)avgGradePoint
FROM CLASS
JOIN STUDENT
ON student.student_id = class.student_id
JOIN course
ON course.course_id = class.course_id
group by 1;
```